# How to find records by closest data to today

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, query-builder

I'm trying to get the closest upcoming match to today, but instead, I get the latest created record with the code I write. How can I change the code to find the date closest to today?

```
$upcomingMatch = Match::leftjoin('scores', 'matches.id', '=', 'scores.match_id')
    ->where(function ($where) {
        $where->where('matches.away_team_id', '=', '1')
            ->orWhere('matches.home_team_id', '=', '1');
    })
    ->whereNull('scores.id')
    ->latest('matches.match_date')
    ->first();
```

Comment: try to filter data first. In where select all upcoming matches and get, not latest, but first. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
orderBy(DB::raw('ABS(DATEDIFF(matches.match_date, NOW()))'))->
```

Try this and it must work.